# Custom Windows desktop Controls .NET Core

Tags: c#, custom-controls, desktop-application, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to create custom windows form .NET Core controls in a class library named `BaseControls`.
The Project is a Class Library with .NET Core 3.1 target framework and custom control is `Button`.
I've changed the project file and coded the class file as below. But when I want to add that button control on a form, I face an error.
Here is my code and an image that should describe the problem:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
      <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BaseControls
{
    public class MyButton: System.Windows.Forms.Button
    {
        public MyButton()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like you didn't succeed with adding the image...

Answer (score 0):

According to this Microsoft [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/winforms#add-nuget-packages)  you might need to update\install the nuget packages:

```
dotnet add .\CompanyManagement\BaseControls.csproj package MetroFramework
dotnet add .\CompanyManagement\BaseControls.csproj package MetroFramework.Design
dotnet add .\CompanyManagement\BaseControls.csproj package MetroFramework.Fonts
```

If that does not fix the issue you could check all the requirements, or consider creating a new WinForms project with the Net CLI or the IDE, and that will set up everything for you.